# MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance displaying wrong coordinates

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm trying to set approx a 10 mile range around the current location of the user when my mapView loads.
Here is my Objective C code in viewDidLoad:

```
self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];


//Set initial scope of map
CLLocationDistance mapWidith = 16000;
CLLocationDistance mapHeight = 16000;
CLLocationCoordinate2D userLocation = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation, mapHeight , mapWidith);
[self.mapView setRegion: region
               animated:false];
```

When I run it's starting with the correct zoom (I think) but randomly centered in the atlantic ocean somewhere. Not sure if I'm accessing the userLocation coordinate correctly but it seems right. Im pretty new to MKMapView so Im struggling a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userLocation` property on mapView isn't populated yet. You should implement the `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` method and after that point you can reliably use that property (or use the location sent to you).

Comment: +1 Agreed, though I might suggest only doing this once (have some Boolean that keeps track of this). If you want it to follow the user, don't rely upon this being called again in the future, but rather set `userTrackingMode` of the `MKMapView` to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow` or `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithDirection`. Manually updating the `region` manually repeatedly can yield an annoying UX.